# Struts how to add new action and new form to existing form

Tags: jsp, struts, action

I have an existing form which has an existing action which works great, I need to add to this a browse button to attach files in this same JSP.

To do this I added enctype="multipart/form-data" to the form to add support for the attachment but I was getting an error with the existing action cause it does not support it. So ok, I'll create a separate action for the file attachments

So I do the following:

```
<html:form action="/existingAction" method="POST" >
    ...
    --THIS IS ADDED
    <html:form action="/newAction" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <table>
            <tr>
                    <td><html:file size="55" alt="Browse" property="attachmentFile" styleId="attachmentFile"" /></td>
                <html:submit value="AddDoc"/>
                </td>               
            </tr>
        </table>
    </html:form>
    --END OF NEW CODE
    ...
    <html:submit value="completed"/>
</html:form>
```

and in struts config I add an entry for the new action:

```
<action path="/newAction" type="com.action.AttachmentAction"
    scope="request" name="myForm" validate="false">

    <forward name="done" path="/forward/complete.do" />
</action> 

<action path="/existingAction" type="com.action.ExistingAction"
           scope="request" name="myForm" validate="false">

      <forward name="done" path="/forward/complete.do" />
</action>
```

but it's not working, the jsp after the new code does not display in the GUI.. how can I add a new file attachments with a different Action to an existing form/Action?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure which version of struts you using but in v1.2 , having 2 form action on single jsp might not be possible.Saying that u can say something like that
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="/newAction" method="post">
On browse button , input file type as file and you are good to go.

Comment: Hi, if it's possible how can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

You can't nest forms like that, it's not even legal HTML.

Either have two forms, or use a single form and fix whatever the underlying issue is.

Comment: underlying issue cannot be fixed. So that just leaves me having the two forms i have but i have to unnest them. So what do I do in the existing action to be able to process info from both forms? 1 action takes care of adding attachments, the second needs to be able to work with all the existing info plus the file attached by the other action.

Comment: @user1994202 That's simply not how it works. What makes you think you can't fix the underlying problem?

Comment: Cause the underlaying problem is that the existing action inherites from another action class where enctype="multipart/form-data" is not supported so it's throwing an error, I cannot remove this inheritance since it's code used by a lot of other application, not just mine.

Comment: @user1994202 And the action is tied so strongly to the underlying functionality that you can't just create a new action and re-use that functionality?!

Comment: +1 for Dave Newton. @user1994202 The real problem there is the unsupported enctype="multipart/form-data" in the first action. Please give us more details about this problem, I am sure we'll manage to help you then. Anyway, remove this form into another form. It won't get you anywhere.